# Pasting values in a different column depending on a Data Validation drop-down selection

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Suppose I have the following setting on a Google Sheet:

[image: Google Sheets Example]

Column A containing a list of different items (Apple/Melon/Grapes), column B containing Data Validation drop-down menus with either option 1 or 2.

What I want is that if I select option 1 for any of the items, the value of the corresponding cell in column A is going to pasted in D2. If I select option 1 for another item, the value will be pasted in D3, and so forth, thus building a secondary list without leaving any blank cells in between. If I select option 2, the item should be ignored.

Ideally, the order of the items in column D would follow my actions chronologically, i.e. if the item in A3 is the first item I select option 1 for, then it shall be on the top of the column D list at all times, even if later on I select option 1 for A1 as well (which shall then sit on the second position of the D list).

Is it possible to be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via Apps Script with a simple [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger, using its [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).

- Select **Tools > Script editor** to open the Apps Script editor.
- Copy this function and save the project (check inline comments):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
   // Get the range that was edited (column, row, sheet, value):
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var value = range.getValue();
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Name of your sheet (the tab) (please change if necessary)
  // Check that edited column is B, edited value is 1, and edited sheet is "Sheet1":
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetName && col === 2 && value === 1) {
    // Get length of non-empty cells in column D:
    var columnD = sheet.getRange("D:D").getValues().map(function(item) {
      return item[0];
    }).filter(function(item) {
      return item !== "";
    });
    var firstEmptyRow = columnD.length + 1; // First empty row in column D
    var itemToCopy = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue(); // Get value from column A to copy
    sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, 4).setValue(itemToCopy); // Write value to column D
  }
}
```

- Now, every time you edit column B and the edited value is `1`, the corresponding option from column A will get copied to column D.

#### Reference:

- [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Event objects: Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Answer (score 0):

delete range **D2:D** and paste in **D2** cell:

```
=FILTER(A:A; B:B=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the results are still dynamic. I need that once "grapes" hits D2, it will always be in that cell no matter what other options I select on the remaining items. With your formula, if I select 1 for "grapes", very well, it goes to D2, but if I then select 1 for "apples", then apples is the new D2 and "grapes" is pushed to D3.

Comment: I see, in that case you will need a script

Comment: Any tips on what it would look like?